# Keyboard shortcuts hijacked?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, sonoma

I had a bunch of shortcuts working under ctrl-option+{arrow keys} but after I updated to Sonoma 14.3 these stopped working.

Did the OS take these in some way? Is there some way for me to find out how these are being routed?